# Why is locator() broken in RStudio?

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

Does anyone know how to fix when RStudio is breaking the `locator()` function? If I plot

```
plot(1:10)
```

then use `locator()` to click on the same points (1:10), this is what I get after I click the Finish button.

```
locator(type = 'p', col = 'red')
```

[image: rstudio]

```
$x
 [1] 1.265369 2.226131 3.172336 4.147655 5.064746 6.040065
 [7] 6.986270 7.947032 8.893237 9.868556

$y
 [1] 1.437224 2.361029 3.265178 4.169328 5.093133 5.997282
 [7] 6.901432 7.825237 8.729386 9.633536
```

However, if I do the same thing in the R GUI rather than RStudio, then it works just fine:

[image: r]

I've tried restarting my session, using `dev.off()`, and restarting RStudio but the problem persists. Am I missing something simple here, or maybe it's a bug in RStudio?

R version 3.3.1

RStudio 0.99.903

Mac OSX 10.11.6

Comment: you might get more useful responses on the RStudio forums ... don't know if RStudio employees/staff follow SO ...

Comment: I can try that. I am just hoping someone in the SO community has a solution first. Maybe I have a strange setting or something...

Comment: Works fine for me. Windows 7, R 3.3.1, Rstudio 0.99.903

Comment: Hmm, so it's a Mac specific problem then likely. Any Linux users have the same issue? Maybe it's tied into Quartz?

Comment: This is indeed an OS X specific problem, relating to the resolution of the graphics device. Can you try the preview release of RStudio and see if the issue is resolved there? https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: Yes, the new version of RStudio (1.0.39) resolves the issue.